# How to find the nearest neighbor in Hive? Any windowing function?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

Given a table

> ```
> $cat data.csv
>
> ID,State,City,Price,Flag
> 1,CA,A,95,0
> 2,CA,A,96,1
> 3,CA,A,195,1
> 4,NY,B,124,0
> 5,NY,B,128,1
> 6,NY,C,24,0
> 7,NY,C,27,1
> 8,NY,C,29,0
> 9,NY,C,39,1
> ```

Expected Result:

```
ID0, ID1
1,2
4,5
6,7
8,7
```

for each ID with Flag=0 above, we want to find another ID from Flag=1, with the same "State" and "City", and the nearest Price.

I have two rough stupid ideas:

Method 1.

```
Use a left outer join with the table itself on 
    (a.State=b.State and a.City=b.city and a.Flag=0 and b.Flag=1),
     where a.Flag=0 and b.Flag=1, 

    and then use RANK() over (partitioned by a.State,a.City order by a.Price - b.Price) as rank
    where rank=1
```

Method 2.

```
Use a left outer join with the table itself, 
on 
(a.State=b.State and a.City=b.city and a.Flag=0 and b.Flag=1),
 where a.Flag=0 and b.Flag=1, 

and then Use Distribute by a.State,a.City Sort by Price_Diff ASC limit 1
```

What's the best way to find the nearest neighbor in Hive? 
Any valuable tips will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.id, b.id , min(abs(b.price-a.price)) as delta 
from data as a 
     inner join data as b 
            on a.country=b.country and 
               a.flag=0 and b.flag=1 and 
               a.city=b.city 
group by a.id, b.id  
order by delta asc;
```

This returns

```
1   2   1  <---
8   7   2  <---
6   7   3  <--- 
4   5   4  <--- 
8   9   10
6   9   15
1   3   100
```

The problem is that the last 3 rows have the same id used into the first 4.

```
select a.id as id0, b.id as id1, abs(b.price-a.price) as delta, 
       rank() over ( partition by a.country, a.city order by abs(b.price-a.price) ) 
from data as a 
      inner join data as b 
            on a.country=b.country and 
            a.flag=0 and b.flag=1 and 
            a.city=b.city;
```

This will return

```
   id0 id1 prc rank
    1   2   1   1  <---
    1   3   100 2
    4   5   4   1  <---
    8   7   2   1  <--- 
    6   7   3   2
    8   9   10  3
    6   9   15  4
```

We are missing 6,7 and this is somehow correct.

```
6,NY,C,24,0 
7,NY,C,27,1
8,NY,C,29,0
9,NY,C,39,1
```

The lowest price difference for (6,7),(6,9),(8,7),(8,9) is in (8,7). (ambiguous join)

I think you will love this video about this topic : [Big Data Analytics Using Window Functions](https://www.qubole.com/resources/webinar/big-data-analytics-using-window-functions/)